# Adding text to a rectangle

Tags: javascript, d3.js, position, treemap

Is it possible to add a piece of text in the centre of multiple rectangles in a D3 treemap chart? So what i'm after is something like this:

[image]

As you can see by the picture, I want to have text appear once in the middle of each “section” (different colours) on the chart. Is it possible to do this with D3? If so how would I achieve it.

Currently I've managed to have it appear on each individual rectangle, like so:

```
 cell.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.dx / 2; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d.dy / 2; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text("test")
       .style("opacity", function(d) { console.log(this.getComputedTextLength());d.w = this.getComputedTextLength(); return d.dx > d.w ? 1 : 0; });
```

Full code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/noobiecode/9ev9qjt3/74/

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For appending these texts, we first need to find the corresponding data. Right now, `nodes` have data regarding all the different depths (parents and children), but for these texts we only need the data for the second depth (depth == 2).

So, we first get the data:

```
var parents = treemap.nodes(root)
    .filter(function(d) { return d.depth == 2 });
```

It gives us an array with three objects, so we are in the right way. This array (`parents`) have all we need to position the texts (`x`, `y`, `dx`, `dy`, `name`).

Then, we bind this data to the texts:

```
var parentsText = svg.selectAll(".parentsText")
    .data(parents)
    .enter()
    .append("text");
```

After that, we append the texts:

```
parentsText.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
     .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
     .attr("x", function(d){ return d.x + d.dx/2})
     .attr("y", function(d){ return d.y + d.dy/2})
     .text(function(d){ return d.name})
     .attr("class", "parentText");
```

And this is the resulting fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/9ev9qjt3/94/

You can also have the texts for each individual rectangle and for the group (but, in that case, you may want to move away some overlapping texts): http://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/9ev9qjt3/95/